# Easy and Fast Git rebase/reword

Tags: git, rebase

I'm working alone on a Git repository for months. I'd like now to push my commits to a public repository, however, I'd like to improve the commit messages (mainly translate them to English).

I know I can do `git rebase -i` then reword each message. But that will open my editor for each message I want to edit and that's too long for me (hundreds of commits to reword). I'd rather be able to edit the messages at once and apply the modifications.

I'm looking for such a tool that allows me to edit the commit messages on a single window and apply the changes at once in background. For instance, I could have the list of commit messages, I could double-click on a message to edit it, change another, go back to fix a typo and when I'm done with all the changes, I could apply them at once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass a script to rewrite commit messages to `filter-branch`:

```
git filter-branch -f --msg-filter "...script command here..."
```

It should be easy to massage the plain commit message output:

```
git log --pretty=tformat:%B
```

Into a Perl, Python or sed script that replaces it with the corrected version.

Comment: hm, would be nice to have an answer that requires even less thinking on my own :)